# Espaço vazio em Explode em String PHP

Tags: php, explode

Olá, estou tendo problemas ao usar um EXPLODE em uma String PHP.
Usei um espaço como delimitador mas preciso pegar quando forem 3 espaços seguidos como uma posição no Array. É um exercício de um decoder de código morse. A palavra é formada ok mas o espaço entre elas não consigo colocar na String de saída. Se colocasse outro delimitador funcionaria perfeitamente, mas pelo exercício não posso usar outro, e preciso conseguir verificar quando é um espaço só ou quando são 3. O código deve pegar o código morse e transformar em texto...

Muito obrigado.

```
<?php
$morse = [
        ' ' => '   ',
        'A' => '.-', 
        'B' => '-...', 
        'C' => '-.-.', 
        'D' => '-..', 
        'E' => '.', 
        'F' => '..-.', 
        'G' => '--.', 
        'H' => '....', 
        'I' => '..', 
        'J' => '.---' , 
        'K' => '-.-', 
        'L' => '.-..', 
        'M' => '--',
        'N' => '-.', 
        'O' => '---', 
        'P' => '.--.', 
        'Q' => '--.-', 
        'R' => '.-.', 
        'S' => '...', 
        'T' => '-', 
        'U' => '..-',
        'V' => '...-',
        'W' => '.--',
        'X' => '-..-',
        'Y' => '-.--',
        'Z' => '--..'
    ];
    
        $saida = '';
        $mensagem = ".... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. .";

            $letras = explode('', $mensagem);
            foreach($letras as $i => $value)
            {
                $saida .= array_search($letras[$i],$morse);
                
            }
    
            
            echo $saida;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sobre o problema com os espaços, se inspecionar a variável `$letras`, vai perceber que ele gera dois `$values` **""** (vazio) para cada três espaços. Isso acontece porque os espaços estão sendo usados pelo `split / explode`, logo, ele pega tudo que estiver entre os espaços. Para três espaços "vazios" sequentes, entre eles, o retorno é **""** (vazio).

Apesar de existirem outras formas, preferi manter seu raciocínio, acrescentando no `foreach`:

- para toda vez que ele encontra um `$value` vazio, ele acrescenta um espaço, caso contrário, pega o valor na variável `$morse`.
- no final, ele limpa os espaços desnecessários, imprimindo `HEY JUDE` ao invés de `HEY  JUDE`.

```php
<?php

    function morse($mensagem) {
    
        $morse = [
            'A' => '.-', 
            'B' => '-...', 
            'C' => '-.-.', 
            'D' => '-..', 
            'E' => '.', 
            'F' => '..-.', 
            'G' => '--.', 
            'H' => '....', 
            'I' => '..', 
            'J' => '.---' , 
            'K' => '-.-', 
            'L' => '.-..', 
            'M' => '--',
            'N' => '-.', 
            'O' => '---', 
            'P' => '.--.', 
            'Q' => '--.-', 
            'R' => '.-.', 
            'S' => '...', 
            'T' => '-', 
            'U' => '..-',
            'V' => '...-',
            'W' => '.--',
            'X' => '-..-',
            'Y' => '-.--',
            'Z' => '--..'
        ];
    
        $saida = '';
        $letras = preg_split("/\s/", $mensagem);
        
        foreach ($letras as $value) {
        
            $saida .= !empty($value) ? array_search($value, $morse) : ' ';
        }
            
        return preg_replace("/\s{2,}/", " ", $saida);
    }
    
    echo morse(".... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. .");
```

Se atentando ao `foreach`, nesse caso, você não precisa passar o id do array, já que a pesquisa é feita com base no `$value`.

Comment: Bom dia Weslley. Não entendi 100% ainda a resolução que usou, sou iniciante ainda na programação. Esse é um exercício do CodeWars, usei como base um código que achei pesquisando mas acabei travando na hora de garantir que ele retornasse as palavras com espaço. Ele retornava "HEYJUDE;' em vez de "HEY JUDE" Mas vou estudar melhor o código. Te agradeço demais, valeu mesmo.

Comment: @WevertonJúnior O que você não entendeu? Como que vc está iniciando, usei algumas coisas "novas" no script: `regex` (uma forma de verificar se o texto obedece uma regra - (`/\s/` traz todos os espaços e `/\s{2,}/` traz sempre onde ocorrer dois ou mais espaços seguidos)). Também usei `Ternário` ao invés de `IF ELSE` e por fim, englobei o código em uma `função` que retorna o resultado do código morse, assim você pode chamar `morse('qualquer código morse')`, quantas vezes quiser.  Se quiser que eu explique melhor alguma parte específica, pode comentar aqui, qualquer coisa eu adiciono na resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Weverton, para facilitar, faça 2 `explodes`: o primeiro com 3 espaços como separador (que dividirá a mensagem em palavras) e um segundo explode com 1 espaço como separador  (que dividirá a palavra em letras).

O seu código ficaria como abaixo. Modifiquei o array para não precisar do `array_search` e usei o `??` para o caso do código morse inexistente, ele incluir o próprio código na saída (modifique como quiser).

```
<?php
$morse = [
        '.-' => 'A', 
        '-...' => 'B', 
        '-.-.' => 'C', 
        '-..' => 'D', 
        '.' => 'E', 
        '..-.' => 'F', 
        '--.' => 'G', 
        '....' => 'H', 
        '..' => 'I', 
        '.---' => 'J' , 
        '-.-' => 'K', 
        '.-..' => 'L', 
        '--' => 'M',
        '-.' => 'N', 
        '---' => 'O', 
        '.--.' => 'P', 
        '--.-' => 'Q', 
        '.-.' => 'R', 
        '...' => 'S', 
        '-' => 'T', 
        '..-' => 'U',
        '...-' => 'V',
        '.--' => 'W',
        '-..-' => 'X',
        '-.--' => 'Y',
        '--..' => 'Z'
    ];
    
    $saida = '';
    $mensagem = ".... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. .";

    //Divide mensagem em palavras
    $palavras = explode('   ', $mensagem);
    foreach ($palavras as $palavra) {
        
        //Divide palavra em "letras morse"
        $letras = explode(' ', $palavra);
        foreach ($letras as $letra)
        {
            //Converte "letra morse" para letra do alfabeto e concatena na saída
            $saida .= $morse[$letra] ?? $letra;
        }
        
        //Adiciona espaço para separar as palavras na saída
        $saida .= ' ';
    }
        
    //Tira espaço extra ao final
    $saida = trim($saida);
    
    //Exibe resultado
    echo $saida;
?>
```

Comment: Cara valeu d+, não tinha pensado por esse ângulo de poder fazer dois explodes. Muito interessante, Valeu mesmo.